# Drupal 9: How to reference a view in a paragraph field type

Tags: view, drupal, paragraph, drupal-9

In my Drupal website, I'm using the paragraphs module to build the pages's main content. One of my paragraph types is called 'News'. This paragraph type contains a field that should reference to a '**recent news items view**'. This view is already created, but I can't figure out the setup to reference this view in my paragraph field. I already tried many configurations and followed a few tutorials, all with the same result.

I think the issue lies with creating the new field. When creating the field, I have to select the field type. According to me, this must be 'Reference > Content'

[image]

Thereafter I must setup the 'Field settings > Type of item to reference'. There I go for 'Content > Content'.

[image]

The problem now is that I can only select my 'content types' as a reference, while I must be able to select a view.

[image]

So my final question is; Which configuration to choose, so I can select a view as output?

Answer (score 2):

Views are not referenceable by a field by default. You need either the Views Reference module:
https://www.drupal.org/project/viewsreference

... or the Block Reference module:
https://www.drupal.org/project/blockreference

This will allow you to add to your paragraph type a field that may reference your 'recent news items' view.

Answer (score 0):

1. Instead of Reference->Content select Reference->Other.
2. On the next step change "Type of item to reference" from Content to View (it's at the bottom of the list).
3. Click "Save field settings"
4. On the next screen click "Save settings"
5. Optionally go to "Manage form display" tab and change widget for the field (by default it's autocomplete field)

Comment: As a note you need to have another module in order to see an option like "Content to View" in the "Type of item to reference" options list. The Drupal 8+ module [Views Reference Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/viewsreference) adds the "Views reference" option to the list.

Answer (score 0):

I made good experience with the module **[viewfield](https://www.drupal.org/project/viewfield)**:

**You can choose:**

1. View
2. Display Mode
3. Options (optional)

**You can use options:**

1. Arguments (contextual filters)
2. Items to display

**Screenshot of a paragraph:**

[image]

**Screenshot of the paragraph type "paragraph_view" with one field:**

[image: Screenshot of the paragraph type "paragraph_view"]